# Trying to identify a sci-fi TV series from late 80's?

Tags: story-identification

We remember a series featuring bug like aliens in black robes with 3 suction fingers. They said to their leader "without you I am nothing" late 80's, early 90's, please help thanks

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the first season of [*War of the Worlds* (1988-1990).](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094578/)

The aliens in the first season were kept alive by radioactivity and would grab someone with one of their arms and take over his body for a while until it decayed.

Their motto was "To life immortal" which seemed ungrammatical.  It should have been "To life eternal" or "To immortality".